# Set javascript variable equal to Storyline variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, articulate-storyline

So I've got a javascript with a pie chart and 5 slices. I want to implement this chart into a Storyline slide. In this Storyline project I've got 5 variables that has got specific values. When a user answers some questions, these values change. At the end of the project these values will be visualized with this Pie Chart.

The Pie chart works perfectly, but now I have to connect these slices with the Storyline variables. How can I do this?

Here you can see how the pie chart is build.

```
// This gives the pie slices a name. //
var myPersoonlijkheid = {
    "Categorie1": 10,
    "Categorie2": 44,
    "Categorie3": 32,
    "Categorie4": 12,
    "Categorie5": 8
```

Can I just say `var=Categorie1` where the numbers are? Or is it more complicated than that? I;ve searched on the internet for some answers, but I couldn't found something, Obviously otherwhise I wouldn't be asking this now. Haha!

So.. Is there someone who can help me? :D I would appriciate it! Thank you!

Comment: where did you try the pie chart? It's not clear whether you were able to include the chart into your slides or not. There are some starter materials [here](https://articulate.com/support/article/javascript-best-practices-and-examples). Take a look at the examples and see if the help.

Comment: Hi Mustafa,
I have made a file with a index.html and a .js file and imported it as a webobject in Storyline. But now I want to connect those two variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it work :D

What I did:

I made a Storyline project where I have 5 sliders. Those sliders have each their own variable (var1, var2, var3, var4 and var5). I created a blank slide where this pie chart is going to be.

Then I made an index.html file. This file contains

```
<body> 
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="pie-chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

I saved this file into a map on the server.

After that I put this Javascript together:

```
// the JS code will first get a reference to the canvas and then set its width and height. To draw on the canvas, we only need a reference to its 2D context which contains all the drawing methods. //
        /*global quotes:true, global $*/

    window.onload = function() {
        var player = window.parent.GetPlayer(); //this piece was missing.//

        var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        myCanvas.width = 300;
        myCanvas.height = 300;
        var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
        // Define what the function. //
        function drawLine(ctx, startX, startY, endX, endY) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
            ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
        }
        // This function draws an arc between the lines. //
        function drawArc(ctx, centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        // This function draws a coloured shape between the lines. //
        function drawPieSlice(ctx, centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, color) {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
            ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            /* drawLine(_ctx,100,100,200,200);
            drawArc(_ctx, 150,150,150, 0, Math.PI/3);
            drawPieSlice(_ctx, 150,150,150, Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2 + Math.PI/4, '#ff0000'); */
        }
        /* This retrieves the value of the Storyline variable 
           (the one between the quote symbols). */
                var var1 = player.GetVar("var1");
                var var2 = player.GetVar("var2");
                var var3 = player.GetVar("var3");
                var var4 = player.GetVar("var4");
                var var5 = player.GetVar("var5");

        // This gives the slices the value from above. //
            var myPersoonlijkheid = {
                "Categorie1": var1,
                "Categorie2": var2,
                "Categorie3": var3,
                "Categorie4": var4,
                "Categorie5": var5
        };
        var Piechart = function(options) {
            this.options = options;
            this.canvas = options.canvas;
            this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            this.colors = options.colors;
            this.draw = function() {
                var total_value = 0;
                var color_index = 0;
                for (var categ in this.options.data) {
                    var val = this.options.data[categ];
                    total_value += val;
                }
                var start_angle = 0;
                for (categ in this.options.data) {
                    val = this.options.data[categ];
                    var slice_angle = 2 * Math.PI * val / total_value;
                    drawPieSlice(this.ctx, this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height / 2, Math.min(this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height / 2), start_angle, start_angle + slice_angle, this.colors[color_index % this.colors.length]);
                    start_angle += slice_angle;
                    color_index++;
                }
            }
        }
        var myPiechart = new Piechart({
            canvas: myCanvas,
            data: myPersoonlijkheid,
            colors: ["#f2f2f2", "#b3dcff", "#1b96ff", "#004682", "#002341"]
        });
        myPiechart.draw();
        }
```

After that I published the Storyline file. And now it works perfectly!

Thanks Mustafa for your help. I appriciate it :D

Comment: Sweet! can you please add a little more context to your answer (i.e project structure, configuration, etc) so that readers know how things fit together. Remember that you had doubts about these things initially. And happy SOing! :)

Answer (score 0):

To get storyline variables in your Javascript code you do something like this:

```
function displayChart(){
    var thePlayer = GetPlayer();
    var var1 = thePlayer.GetVar("variable1");
    var var2 = thePlayer.GetVar("variable2");
    ...

    var myPersoonlijkheid = {
        "Categorie1": var1,
        "Categorie2": var2,
        "Categorie3": var3,
        "Categorie4": var4,
        "Categorie5": var5
    }
   pieChart(myPersoonlijkheid);
}
```

You can use a javascript trigger to run the function above.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question.. But do I put this in the .js file or in the Execute Javascript trigger in Storyline?

Comment: I would try adding this code in its own js file and including it your storyline story_content folder. You can then include it in your storyline html file using a <script> tag. In your js trigger you just call the `displayChart` method. Take a look at the link I sent you above to how that's done in more details.

Comment: I still can't make them connect somehow.. I've put ' <script lang="javascript" src="pie-chart.js" type="text/javascript"> </script> ' in the _story.html_ and the _pie-chart.js_ is in the story_content map. Still it would not respond to the imput in the project.. What should I do now?

Comment: looks like what i'm dealing with - this seems to only work with the `story_flash.html` and not `story.html` I am also looking for way to get variables in the html5 version of storyline - the flash page is the only one where get player() works?